# Ubercart 2.x: Given a product nid, retrieve its manufacturer

Tags: 6, ubercart

I'm trying to figure out how Ubercart stores manufactures.

Currently it's set up as a Vocabulary, but I can't figure out how to grab that info programmatically given a product nid.

Any advice?

Comment: Is this for Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: @Clive: Drupal 6 (added tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 6 taxonomy terms are linked to the node object, Ubercart just piggy-backs off the way Drupal core handles this.

You can use the very handy [`taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary/6) function to grab all of the terms associated with a node in a certain vocabulary. You would use it like so:

```
$vid = 1; // Vocabulary ID
$nid = 1; // Node ID

$node = node_load($nid);
$terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vid);
```